# Proof of Schur Product Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone know how I can find a proof using operators of Schur's Product Theorem? Most proofs I have seen are very terse.

Is there a way to prove it with operators and their matrices? Thanks!

Comment: What don't you like about the Wikipedia proofs?  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem ]

Comment: Maybe you'd like Schur's proof:  [ http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0140&DMDID=DMDLOG_0004&LOGID=LOG_0004&PHYSID=PHYS_0006 ]

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the Wikipedia proof as I am learning the material through an inner product definition with operators. For example, I am confused what $\mu$ means in the Wikipedia proof. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if somebody answered this. The wiki article says "it's easy to show that ...". well, it might be easy, but not for everyone

Answer (score 2):

If the basis $\{v_1, . . . , v_n\}$ is orthonormal, then for any two vectors $v, w$ ∈ $V$
with $v = ∑ a_iv_i$ and $w = ∑ b_jv_j$ , then

$$
⟨v, w⟩ =∑a_ib_j ⟨v_i, v_j ⟩ =∑a_ib_jδ_{ij} = ∑a_ib_i
$$
so if we identify $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the basis (which we will do from now on), the inner product becomes the usual dot product. This is not true if the basis is not orthonormal, and in fact the statement of the problem is false in that case.

If $A$ is positive, by the Spectral Theorem, there is an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{e_1, . . . , e_n\}$ with nonnegative eigenvalues.

In terms of matrices,
$M =∑λ_ie_ie^{T}_i$
with $λ_i ≥ 0$. Similarly, $B$ also has an orthonormal eigenbasis $\{f_1, . . . , f_n\}$ with eigenvalues $ν_j ≥ 0$, so in terms of matrices, $N = ∑ν_jf_jf^{T}_j$.

If we denote the componentwise product of matrices by ○, then
$$L = M ○ N = (∑λ_ie_ie^{T}_i) ○(∑ν_jf_jf^{T}_j)=∑λ_iν_j (e_ie^{T}_i) ○ (f_jf^{T}_j)=
∑
λ_iν_j (e_i ○ f_j)(e_i ○ f_j)^T
$$
Now let the latter matrix $L$ define a positive operator, $R$. If $v ∈ V$ is an arbitrary
vector, then
$$⟨v, Rv⟩ = v^{T}Lv=
∑
λ_iν_jv^T(e_i ○ f_j)(e_i ○ f_j)^{T}v=∑λ_iν_jv^{T}(e_i ○ f_j))^2 ≥ 0
$$
because each term in the sum is nonnegative.